# jqxgrid not loading data

Tags: datagridviewcolumn, jqxgrid

I am trying to lead data from my controller. The queries work right but i cant seem to load the data in the view. If anyone can see my mistake, i will appreciate it.

controller

```
  public ActionResult GetItemList(int RRGroupID)
        {

          var item = ReportEngineHelper.GetReportingEngine(Session).Generate<ItemListQuery>(new Filter()
            {
                Item=new Item()
                {
                    RRGroupID = RRGroupID,

                }
            }).ToQueryModel<ItemName>();
          var listItemName = new List<ItemName>();


            return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

view

```
 var detailsSource =
                            {
                                    url: $.ajax({url: url,
                                                    type: "json",
                                                    data: {RRGroupID:RRGroupID},
                                                                }),
                                    datatype: "json",
                                datafields: [{ name: "ItemID", type: "int" }, { name: "FullItemName" }],
                            };
                            var detailsAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(detailsSource);
                            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
                                source: detailsAdapter,
                                autoheight:true,
                                autowidth: true,
                                columns: [
                           { text: 'Item Name', datafield: 'FullItemName', width: 200, editable: false },
                           { text: 'Unit', width: 100, editable: true },
                           { text: 'Beginning Balance', width: 180, editable: true },
                           { text: 'Loss', width: 80, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right' },
                           { text: 'Quantity Recieved', width: 90, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right'},
                           { text: 'DOS', width: 100, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right' },
                           { text: 'Requested Quantity', width: 100, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right'}
                                ],

                            });
```

Comment: Does your ajax response contains any data? can you check it in developer console...

Comment: The RRGroupID seems to be passed to the controller. which is why i used it like that

Answer (score 0):

```
   //this is your function build grid
   function buildDetail(data){
      var detailsSource:{
              localdata:data,
              datafields: [{ name: "ItemID", type: "int" }, { name: "FullItemName" }],
              type:'json',
           };
           var detailsAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(detailsSource);
                        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
                            source: detailsAdapter,
                            autoheight:true,
                            autowidth: true,
                            columns: [
                       { text: 'Item Name', datafield: 'FullItemName', width: 200, editable: false },
                       { text: 'Unit', width: 100, editable: true },
                       { text: 'Beginning Balance', width: 180, editable: true },
                       { text: 'Loss', width: 80, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right' },
                       { text: 'Quantity Recieved', width: 90, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right'},
                       { text: 'DOS', width: 100, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right' },
                       { text: 'Requested Quantity', width: 100, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right'}
                            ],

                        });
  }


 // now get your data with ajax then build grid.
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({url: url,
             type: "json",
             data: {RRGroupID:RRGroupID},
            success:function(data){ 
               //now call your build function
               buildDetail(data);
             }
        });
 })
```

By this way, you load your data without using jqx.ajax

Comment: i think i have found the problem.. think its could be this: url: $.ajax({url: url,
                                                    type: "json",
                                                    data: {RRGroupID:RRGroupID},
                                                                }),....... no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Yess!! because you don't need $.ajax method. Edit it like example above.

Comment: but i do.. thats the only way i can pass parameter to my controller so far :(

Comment: :) OK I understand your problem. You can use formatUrl option but now, you may not work with this property, I would reansver aganin now.

Comment: i can get value on the console [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] for the ajax,.. object0: ObjectFullItemName: "Isoniazid - (INH) 300mg - Tablet"ItemID: 150

Comment: solved with this ..  url: "../FacilityAdd/GetItemList",
                                data: { RRGroupID: RRGroupID },
                                datatype: "json",
                                datafields: [{ name: "ItemID", type: "int" },
                                { name: "FullItemName", type: 'string' }],.. thanks for ur help

Comment: i have now a new problem :( i just started using jqxgrid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780260/uncaught-error-jqxgrid-missing-references-to-the-following-modules-jqxgrid