# Uncaught Error: jqxGrid: Missing references to the following module(s): jqxgrid.edit.js

Tags: datagridviewcolumn, jqxgrid

i am trying to make editable columns in jqxgrid. But i am having the error
Uncaught Error: jqxGrid: Missing references to the following module(s):  jqxgrid.edit.js but as you can see from below i have used the reference jqxgrid.edit.js , i also have similar problem with columnresize=true propery. Any idea where i messed up?
thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=”en”>
<head>
<title id=”description”>Edit Item</title>
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”/Content/jqx.base.css” type=”text/css” />
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”../../scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxcore.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxdata.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxbuttons.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxscrollbar.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxmenu.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.edit.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxlistbox.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxdropdownlist.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.selection.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.filter.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.sort.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.pager.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/jqxgrid.grouping.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/Scripts/globalize.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function () {
…………..

var detailsAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(detailsSource, { autobind: true });

$(“#jqxgrid”).jqxGrid({
source: detailsAdapter,
selectionmode: ‘singlecell’,
editable: true,
pageable: true,
autoheight:true,

columns: [
{ text: 'Item Name', dataField: 'FullItemName', width: 200, editable: false },
{ text: 'Unit', width: 100, editable: true },
{ text: 'Beginning Balance', width: 180, editable: true },
{ text: 'Loss', width: 80, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right' },
{ text: 'Quantity Recieved', width: 90, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right'},
{ text: 'DOS', width: 100, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right' },
{ text: 'Requested Quantity', width: 100, editable: true, cellsalign: 'right'}
],
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are referring jqxgrid.edit.js at the correct location?

Comment: i think so in the documentation it has to be before jqxgrid.js

Comment: but it's after jqxgrid.js in your code here

Comment: i mean after.. sorry :)

Comment: If you check the Scripts folder, do you see the file?